# How To Use Chrome Developer Profile with Visual Studio Code Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular6, chrome-debugging

Our team working in a angular project using the visual code as the the editor . Each team member have the separate copy of the project(same computer different folder) connected through common git repository. We debug the angular code using the debugger for chrome.all member are working in same workstation using the remote multi user login. but at a time only one person can use the debugger.

i followed the following tutorial and done necessary configuration in launch.json file

https://briandesousa1.wordpress.com/2018/05/12/using-a-chrome-developer-profile-with-visual-studio-code-debugger/

my launch.json file is looks like bellow

```
 "configurations": [
             
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Chrome",
          "url": "http://localhost:4207",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
          "userDataDir": true,
          "runtimeArgs": [
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
            " --profile-directory=Profile 2"
          ]
        }
        ]
```